# Fully visible NSWindow versus not

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

If I have an NSWindow that is behind another window (not necessarily from the same app), is there an easy way to determine if that window is fully visible verses partially visible.

The NSWindow methods tell me if the window is either hidden or at least partially visible.